# How can i decode tk-06 tracker data in c#?

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a tk-06 tracker and I want to write code to decode it.

This is my code:

```
try
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1000];
    int byteRec;

    while (true)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            byteRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
            if (byteRec > 0)
            {
                data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, byteRec);
                break;
            }
        }

        FillLstMsg(data);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

But it shows me this: xx IE! or show this xx ??!!
what happened? how can i solve this?
tk-06 is gps module that send data to server with sokcet.

Comment: You'll need to show us some documentation on what a TK-06 tracker is, and what data those bytes represent.

Comment: "That send data to server" is not very specific! Are you sure it's UTF8?

Comment: no i'm not sure,how can i understand send UTF-8?

Comment: In your code you are attempting to interpret it as UTF-8, so you must have gotten that idea from somewhere? You need to check the documentation for the device. If I were to guess, I'd guess that if it's gps data, it'd probably be ASCII not UTF-8.